# The term ' ' not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32

I am trying to make a water-level capacitatnce sensor similar to the one here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40TjjWLljaU

So I downloaded the code provided in the description. I think I did all the necessary pre-requesits.

I opened the file where the code is downloaded and went to terminal> run task > build IDF. I get this error. What I understood is that it is trying to fetch the code from the original users directory. So my questoion would be, how can I make it run the code from my computer?

```
The term '/LOCATION_OF_FILE_IMPORTED' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was  included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:61
+ /home/****/.espressif/python_env/idf4.2_py3.6_env/bin/python <<<<  /home/kris/esp/esp-idf/tools/idf.py build
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (/home/****/.esp..._env/bin/python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Thank you for your time and help in advance.